# Woocommerce product tabs (show other products)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woo commerce in my wordpress store online, I got a requirement that when a product is clicked and we navigate to the product detail page. I need to show the tabs into the product page like in the link

http://www.designbyhumans.com/shop/t-shirt/men/wolf-i/17011/

In this link two additional tabs are shown 
1. Phone Cases
2. Art prints

Is there any way to achieve this is woo commerce?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom tabs using woocommerce filters
The below code adds an extra tab called 'Product Description'.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
// Adds the new tab
    $tabs['desc_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Product Description', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );
}
function woo_new_product_tab_content()  {

    // The new tab content
    $prod_id = get_the_ID();
    echo '<p>'.get_post_meta($prod_id,'product_description',true).'</p>';

}
```

You would need to fetch the product data into these tabs. In the above example data from a custom field(product_description) is fetched into the tab.